# Subtract two times in crystal lang

Tags: crystal-lang

I am writing a small benchmark for crystal, and want to compare the time taken without any other library.

In programming language like ruby I would do this:

```
t = Time.new
sleep 3
puts "Time: #{Time.new - t}s"
```

Is there a way to get current monotonic clock time and subtract it from another time to get accuracy up to at least 3 decimal places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The typical time representation provided by the operating system is
> based on a "wall clock" which is subject to changes for clock
> synchronization. This can result in discontinuous jumps in the
> time-line making it not suitable for accurately measuring elapsed
> time.
>
> ...
>
> As an alternative, the operating system also provides a monotonic
> clock. Its time-line has no specfied starting point but is strictly
> linearly increasing.
>
> This **monotonic clock should always be used for measuring elapsed time**.
>
> A reading from this clock can be taken using [`.monotonic`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.32.1/Time.html#monotonic:Time::Span-class-method):
>
> ```
> t1 = Time.monotonic
> # operation that takes 1 minute
> t2 = Time.monotonic
> t2 - t1 # => 1.minute (approximately)
> ```
>
> The execution time of a block can be measured using [`.measure`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.32.1/Time.html#measure(&):Time::Span-class-method):
>
> ```
> elapsed_time = Time.measure do
>   # operation that takes 20 milliseconds
> end
> elapsed_time # => 20.milliseconds (approximately)
> ```
>
> -- [Time - github.com/crystal-lang/crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.32.1/Time.html#measuring-time)

* Emphasis mine.

So your example would be basically the same, but with `Time.monotonic` instead of `Time.new`.